# Bootstrap Modal Not Showing - Laravel - AdminLTE

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-modal, adminlte

i'm using an [AdminLTE package](https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE) with Laravel to give me the AdminLTE theme for my app.

I cannot get the modal to launch at all. If I copy the contents of my `form.blade.php` into my `index.blade.php` it works. Although the way i have coded my controller & views i need them to be independent files.

- Index.blade.php <- view serving the datatable
- form.blade.php <-- view serving the modal from click edit on index.blade.php
- CostCenterController.php <-- Controller responsible for both views.

### CostCenterController.php

So in my controller I have a function that returns the results with server side processing into my datatable, this is just the part showing how each item in the table is generated, specifically with the btn-group for the edit function.:

```php
 $data = array();
        if (!empty($costcenters)){
            foreach ($costcenters as $costcenter){
                $editURL = "delete/".$costcenter->id;
                $temp['name'] = $costcenter->name;
                $temp['code'] = $costcenter->code;
                $action = '';
                $action .= '
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <a href="'.route("costcenter.edit",$costcenter->id).'" class="btn btn-info modal-content"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                 <a href="'.route("costcenter.delete",$costcenter->id).'"  type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                </div>
                ';

                $temp['action'] = $action;
                array_push($data, $temp);

            }//end for each
        }// end if empty

        $recordsTotal = count($recordsTotal);
        echo json_encode(array('recordsTotal' => $recordsTotal, 'data' => $data, 'recordsFiltered' => $recordsTotal));
```

In my `index.blade.php` i have nothing of importance or relevance really.

### form.blade.php

I created a `form.blade.php` so when I hit edit, a route calls this view with the data needed from the edit function in the associated controller. This view works as plain html if opened in a new tab.

```php
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" >
@if ($mode == 'edit')
        {!! Form::model($costcenter,array('route'=>array('costcenter.update',$costcenter->id),'id'=>'costcenter-form')) !!}
        @else
        {!! Form::open(array('url'=>'costcenter/store','method'=>'post','data-toggle'=>'validator','id'=>'costcenter-form')) !!}
        @endif
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
             @if ($mode == 'edit') 
                 Edit {{$costcenter->name}}'s Cost Center
                 @else 
                 Create Cost Center 
             @endif
            </h5>
            <button aria-label="Close" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true"> &times;</span></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
              <div class="form-group">
                  {!! Form::label('name','Cost Center Name:',['class'=>'control-label']) !!}
                  {!! Form::text('name',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Enter Cost Center Name','data-error'=>"Please enter the name of the cost center",'required'=>true]) !!}
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  {!! Form::label('code','CostCenter Code:',['class'=>'control-label']) !!}
                  {!! Form::text('code',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Cost Center code as it appears in SYSPRO.','data-error'=>"Invalid Cost Center Code.",'required'=>true]) !!}
              </div>

            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
          {!! Form::submit('Save',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])!!}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: add `#modal` in href instead of route.

Comment: But i need to call the edit function in the controller as more arrays need to be parsed back to the edit modal.

Comment: that it won't work, it gets redirected to specific page URL, instead of opening modal.